# How difficult is source-level detection of arrays of runtime bounds?

Tags: c++, arrays, static-analysis, c++14

The (accepted) [proposal for "Runtime-sized arrays with automatic storage duration (N3639)"](http://isocpp.org/files/papers/N3639.html) asserts that

> Stack overflow becomes more likely, in particular if the size depends on external input and is not properly checked. **Some environments might therefore prohibit the use of the feature. Such a prohibition can be easily enforced with a static analysis tool.**

I do not consider enforcement to be easy if it requires the analyzer to implement a full C++ compiler.

Consider the following code:

```
template<typename T>
inline void array_user( const T& x )
{
    int a[f(traits<T>::omega)];
}
```

It looks to me like the analysis needs to be repeated for each use of `array_user<T>` and consider:

- Applicable specializations of `traits<T>` discoverable at the point of use of `array_user<T>`
- Whether `traits<T>::omega` is a compile-time constant expression (either via `constexpr` or C++03 approaches such as `enum`)
- The type of `traits<T>::omega`
- Whether the applicable overload of `f()` (at the point of use of `array_user<T>` and possibly found via ADL) is `constexpr`

Am I missing something?  Is it possible to enforce such a restriction without going through full compilation?

Can code be written in such a way to simplify verification of non-use of runtime bounds?

Comment: Considering that [N3652 makes almost everything legal in `constexpr` functions in C++1y](http://isocpp.org/files/papers/N3652.html), writing a general static analyzer will require you to implement an interpreter as well as a compiler.

Comment: @Casey: Is it guaranteed that every `constexpr` function will return a compile-time constant if its parameters are compile-time constants?  Or can it depend on specializations of templates consumed (possibly indirectly) by the `constexpr` function?  I still feel like that can be determined via type analysis, without actually computing the result of the `constexpr` function (and all the execution that entails)

Comment: I'm not worried about a general static analyzer for the purposes of this question, just one to detect use of runtime bounds.

Comment: Comment was really meant generally, and not to address this specific question. `constexpr` functions are only guaranteed to be evaluated at compile time when used in a context that requires a constant expression - I'm certain how they interact with arrays of runtime bound. So it may be necessary to determine if the arguments are constant expressions to determine if an array has static or runtime bound.

Comment: @Casey: I agree, that's what I meant by the bulleted list in my question.  But you allude to something else.  In C++11, an array bound is required to be a compile-time constant, and so it forces the compiler to evaluate any `constexpr` functions at compile-time.  In C++14, would the compiler be able to choose to make an array of runtime bound even when a statically-sized array would be feasible, and then evaluate `constexpr` functions at runtime?

Comment: The array declaration wording favors static bounds(N3690 8.3.4p1): "If the expression ... is a core constant expression whose value is N, the type of the identifier of D is “derived-declarator-type-list array of N T”. Otherwise, the type of the identifier of D is “derived-declarator-type-list array of runtime bound of T” ...". I believe that an implementation is required to produce a static-sized array if possible.

Comment: @Casey: That's a relief.  However, it still might mess up 5.19p6, which uses an array bound as an example of "a context where an integral constant expression is required".

Answer (score 1):

If I were tasked with writing an analyzer to statically verify non-use of runtime-bounds, I would reject the above code.  I would require all array declarations to either use an integral literal for the bound or be annotated to have the compiler reject runtime-bounds.

```
template<typename T>
inline void array_user( const T& x )
{
    int a[f(traits<T>::omega)];
    sizeof a;
}
```

However, given the number of compilers that currently provide C99-style VLAs in C++ mode as an extension, I'm not confident that they would actually conform to the C++14 behavior of forbidding `sizeof`.

Comment: Clang/gcc allow `decltype` for VLAs, and clang allows `typeinfo()` as well. I think template deduction is the only way to force static bounds easily that works in today's compilers ([example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=8f37bb9c196e4b0e360d60ead3e03eae-e1204655eaff68246b392dc70c5a32c9)).